# how to make the "pop-up" to allow user upload image to amazon s3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-s3

i'm making a site with MVC 3, and going to allowed user insert image as what stackoverflow does.. simply click the button and something pop up, either upload or with url

may i know how can i make the pop up and upload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found... Using Jquery can almost achieve all effect in Stackoverflow.com